# App uninstalls randomly during testing with Appium on Android

Tags: android, appium, ui-testing

I am trying to test an app on Android using Appium. While interacting with the app manually, it suddenly uninstalls. As I am just getting started with this project, I have little idea why this would occur and this issue doesn't seem to have been a problem for others.

For reference, the person who set up the Appium test server is part of an offshore team and unavailable for contact during the day.

Answer (score 2):

Appium server uninstalls app only if you are starting appium server with command line flag --full-reset, if you don't want to uninstall app, just remove this flag from the command to start server.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been 7 years since this question has been submitted, but for me it works killing all the node process using this command on CMD: taskkill /F /IM node.exe /T

I think is related to all the node.exe old proccess from old drivers and sessions.